# Unix network performance - troubleshooting

Tags: networking

Need some guidance on a Networking issues that started a few days ago and I am not sure how to how to troubleshoot.

**Problem -** Every two minutes or so I lose the ability to access the internet, web surf, streaming audio RDP connections, VOIP call are cut off and so on. This last about 20-30 seconds and then connections are restored.  The odd thing here is, the internet connection stays up and does not appear to be the problem I have monitored the router and all is well, I have called Time warner and had the connection tested.  Although I loose RDP connection, I don’t lose my VPN connection.

**Troubleshooting-** I disconnected EVERY Device from the network and only attached the PC to the router and the PROBLEM disappeared.  I then began to plug in devices one at a time every two hours or so to see what device was the problem.  After all was said and done, I have identified my READYNAS PRO is the cause of the problem.   Each time I unplug it from the network everything returns to normal.

Just in case there was an IP conflict - **I have change the IP.**

Just in case the RJ45 cable was bad - **I have changes the RJ45 cable**

Just in case the NAS Ethernet port went bad - **I moved to the secondary Ethernet Port on the device**

Just in case the Ethernet port was bad on the switch, the **NAS connection was moved to another port.**

How can I find the cause of this problem?

Comment: Hi. Regular or almost regular connectivity failure typically comes from a specific configuration problem, typically caused by local network configuration or a software bug. You would have to diagnose a bit and come up with a more detailed description of how your network works, how the computer is configured and what is in the relevant logs. There are too many unknowns for now.

Answer (score 2):

*Definitely* run **wireshark** through before and through the outage and look for anything suspicious. My wild guess is that your READYNAS might run a (misconfigured) DHCP server and your PC is changing its network configuration all the time.

Comment: Hummmm, DHCP on  the NAS has never been enable, currently it is disabled.   Let me give Wireshark a  try.

Comment: also, run tcpdump -n on the PC and watch if all the traffic ceases during the outage (and when already at that, check ifconfig -a)